# selecting random strings in arrays to print message

Tags: java, arrays

I've been asked to create a programme that stores series of suitable nouns, adjectives and verbs in arrays. These must be set up at the start of programme run. Rather than ask the user, each time it generates letter it just chooses words at random from the appropriate array. The arrays are passed to methods that represent the templates.

I'm new to java, and this is what I have managed to get done below, however shows errors saying void cannot be converted to string for the print message part. I would be glad if someone can help me approach this simple question which i'm struggling on, I don't know if I am doing it correctly :/ . Any help would be much appreciated :)

```
 public static void arrays()
{

        final String []noun = {"face", "eyes", "tender", "lips", "ears", "roses"};
        Random random = new Random();
        int rand1 = random.nextInt(noun.length);


        final String []verb = {"enchant", "dazzle", "cuddle" , "lure", "desire", "dream" };
        Random random2 = new Random();
        int rand2 = random2.nextInt(verb.length);


        final String []adjective = { "Alluring", "Angelic", "Adoring", "Appealing", "Attractive", "beautiful"};
        Random random3 = new Random();
        int rand3 = random3.nextInt(adjective.length);


        String message = printmessage (noun[rand1], verb[rand2], adjective[rand3]);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);

}
    // END arrays

     public static String printmessage(String r1, String r2, String r3)
    {
        String result1;
        String result2;
        String result3;
        String result4;

        result1 = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I would love to " + r2 + " " + r3 + " " + r1 + "\n");
        return result1;
        result2 = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your are my " + r1 + " " + r3 + " " + r2 + "\n");
        return result2;
        result3 = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you always look great in that " + r1 + " , as you always do, since your so" + r3 + "\n");
        return result3;
        result4 = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I get butterflies when I see you in" + r1 + " , you make me " + r2 + " , in your " + r3 + " world" + "\n");
        return result4;

    }
```

Comment: hmm, very romantic code there

Comment: My guess is that you're not writing code in a main method... and instead writing in the class. Show more code so we can see what's wrong..

Comment: Thats all there is to the question stated, what else can there be for the code? @user1071777

Comment: I get butterflies when I see your bunny...sounds dirty

Comment: LOOL oh didn't notice that, its suppose to be a part of loveletter :') @Marshall Tigerus

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
String message = printmessage (rand1, rand2, rand3);
```

You should be passing `String` but instead you are passing `int`

Change it to something like:

```
String message = printmessage (noun[rand1], verb[rand2], adjective[rand3]);
```

EDIT:

Also, since you want to create the String `message` don't remove the `return` but change the method to:

```
public static String printmessage(String r1, String r2, String r3)
```

EDIT EDIT:

You would need to update your `printmessage` function to actually create a `String`, something like `String printmessage = "I would love to " + r2 + " " + r3 + " " + r1 + "\n"`

Comment: Ahh right, I did exactly what you said, it shows 1 more error saying "cannot find symbol" in return printmessage statement, how am I suppose to correct that :/ @Daniel Stanley

Comment: @Arpit you would still need to create the String before you can return it, see `EDIT EDIT`

Comment: I changed it, it came up with more errors saying incompatible type again, void cannot be converted to string, @Daniel Stanley